# change popupmenubutton size(width and height)

Tags: flutter

could you plz tell me how to change the size of popupMenu, like to make it wider and bigger, here is my code, thank you a lot. I didnt find some useful info from stack overflow or google...

```
Widget _threeItemPopup() => PopupMenuButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.more_horiz,
      size: 24,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    onSelected: (value) {
      value();
    },
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            child: Text('Settings')),
        value: () {
          debugPrint('open Settings');
        },
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            child: Text('Flutter.io')),
        value: () {
          debugPrint('goto Flutter.io');
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with fontSize & padding (top/bottom) to make it bigger.

```
  Widget _threeItemPopup() => PopupMenuButton(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 100, bottom: 100), // option 1 : padding on PopupMenuButton
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.more_horiz,
          size: 24,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onSelected: (value) {
          value();
        },
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20, bottom: 20), // option 2 : padding on PopupMenuItem
            child: const SizedBox(
                child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 20, bottom: 20), // option 3 : padding on Text
              child: Text(
                'Settings',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50), // option 4 : play with fontSize
              ),
            )),
            value: () {
              debugPrint('open Settings');
            },
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
            child: const SizedBox(
                child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: Text(
                'Flutter.io',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
              ),
            )),
            value: () {
              debugPrint('goto Flutter.io');
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Comment: thank you bro for you explanation, it indeed works:)

Answer (score 7):

You can set any size of the popup menu, for example 500x1000 (no larger than the screen size), but you lose the automatic calculation of its height and now you have to keep track of it yourself.

```
PopupMenuButton(
    ...
    constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(width: 500, height: 1000),
    itemBuilder:...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the height of the menu remains the height of the screen, so in order to control it, I added this line **BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 300)**.

```
PopupMenuButton(
        ...
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 300),
        itemBuilder:...
```

Answer (score 0):

On [`PopupMenuButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html)'s `child`, you can use `SizedBox` to provide the size you want. Also in your case you can just increase the icon size. Same goes for `PopupMenuItem`

```dart
PopupMenuButton(
        child: const SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child:...,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child:
                Container(width: 100.0, height: 200,....),
```

Comment: thank you Yeasin for you info!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this and don't want to lose out on automatic height or width calculation

```
constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 200),
```

or

```
constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 300),
```